# Powershell commands not working correctly via batch file

Tags: windows-10, script, powershell-5.0

The script receives a parameter sent by the batch file, reads a Music Logs file and generates a list with a header and two columns containing the Music name and the LUFS value of each music, according to a range of LUFS values.

When I run the command outside the batch file the script works correctly, but when I run it via batch file the list is generated incorrectly.

Script:

```
Param(
     [decimal]$env:_vLUF
)

[decimal]$vLUFps = $env:_vLUF

$files = "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\List Music FOR NORMALIZATION.txt"
$logs = "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Logs_Musics"

# READ LOG files of Musics and generates the List Music FOR NORMALIZATION.txt ($files)

$logMatches = Select-String -Path "C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\Logs_Musics\*.*" -Pattern '(?<I>^ +I:) +(?<LUFS>.+)|(?<I>^Input Integrated:) +(?<LUFS>.+)' -List | Select-Object -Property FileName -ExpandProperty Matches
    $results = foreach ($log in $logMatches) {
        $pos = $log.Filename.IndexOf("_")
        $leftPart = $log.Filename.Substring(0, $pos)
        $rightPart = $log.Filename.Substring($pos+1)
        $LUFS = $log.Groups | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "LUFS" }
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Música = $rightPart
            LUFS = [decimal]$($LUFS.Value -replace " .*")
        }
    }

$vLUFpsLess= ($vLUFps)+ (-0.9)
$vLUFpsGreat= ($vLUFps)+ (-0.5)

$results | Where-Object {($_.LUFS -lt $vLUFpsLess) -or ($_.LUFS -gt $vLUFpsGreat) } | Out-file $files
```

Command executed in the batch file to run the script:

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File "D:\z_Batchs and Scripts\Batchs\LUFS_Normalize\ArqsNorms_LUFS_pass.ps1" %_vLUF%
```

The `%_vLUF%` variable is the parameter passed to the script.

List correctly generated by the script run outside the batch file:
[image]

List generated, incorrectly, by the script run via batch file:
[image]

Note:
Via batch file, the script cut the music name with more characters and also cut the LUFS column.

The Out-file command is not generating the .txt file correctly when the script is executed via batch file. Do I need to add some other command to my script so that it runs correctly via batch file?

Comment: I don't see a batch file and I don't know HOW you are running the batch file.

Comment: @Señor CMasMas I edited my question and added more information, ok?

Comment: @Señor CMasMas Hi Señor CMasMas, the batch and the script are in the same folder, however the batch reads audio files that are in a folder on my Desktop, so I use the `pushd` command so that it can read the files from the folder on Desktop. Could the `pushd` command be the cause of this problem? If so, how can we troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: I don't have an answer to that without debugging your script.. but I CAN tell you.. how to debug your script.  It will take a *little* learning to figure out how to debug powershell.. but it is EASY to get started.  Add `Set-PSDebug -Step` to the beginning of your powershell script.  When you run it, it will break on each line.  You can then use `s` to go to a PS prompt and look at your variables.. even run your commands from there and see what is different.

Comment: @Señor CMasMas OK, I'll try this... a question: can I do this even if the script is being executed via batch file?

Comment: YUP!  I just tried it. :)  You might need to move the Set-PSDebug command into the first part of your script (didnt try) but it will work.  You might just play with it from powershell itself to get used to the debugger.  Good luck! :)  You script looks cool.

Comment: @Señor CMasMas Thanks, I think I found a bug and answered my own question... in debbug, I didn't find any errors in the code, but it seems that powershell behaves differently when run as administrator and when run in normal mode via file batch. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

This is the list generated correctly by the script when it is executed, as administrator, via batch file:
[image]

This is the list generated incorrectly by the script when it is executed, without being an administrator, via batch file:
[image]

This is the Paragraph in the batch file that will generate the Log files and run the powershell script:

```
REM ============================================== PARAGRAPH GENERATES LOGS ============================================
:LOGFILES
cls
mode 111,08


  FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('where .:*.* ^|findstr /vi "_LOUDNORM  _EBU"') DO (
          ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "%%a" -af ebur128 -f null NUL 2> "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\LOG_%%~na%%~xa"
         )

REM                                           Run the Powershell script in normal mode:
REM powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File "D:\z_Batchs e Scripts\Batchs\Normaliza_LUFS\ArqsNorms_LUFS_pass.ps1" %_vLUF%

REM                                           Run the Powershell script in administrator mode:
REM powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \"D:\z_Batchs e Scripts\Batchs\Normaliza_LUFS\ArqsNorms_LUFS_pass.ps1\" -_vLUF %_vLUF%'"
```

There is no problem in the script or in any command of the script, we must make an analysis regarding execution priorities of a script when it is executed via batch file.

The `mode` command in the batch file defines the screen size (width x height) that will be displayed to the user when the batch is executed.

When we run the script in administrator mode, by the test I did, it takes control of the processing and, in this case, the Out-file command generates the information according to what is defined in the script, thus correctly generating the file text.

When we run the script in normal mode, it does not take control of the processing and the Out-file command generates the text file with the size of the screen width defined in the paragraph of the batch file. As there is a music whose name is longer than 111 characters (which is the value defined in the `mode` command of the batch file) the command is cutting the rest of the file information and everything after 111 characters is not written to the text file.

I don't know if this would be a bug, but we should analyze that every powershell script that is executed via batch file, would have to have full priority when executing its commands, regardless of being called in admin mode or in normal mode.

Comment: I have no explanation for the difference, but if you want to prevent columns from getting truncated, use `Out-File` with a sufficiently large `-Width` argument - but note that in Windows PowerShell each line gets padded to that width. Alternatively, consider using a _structured_ text format to export your data instead of the _for-display_ format that `Out-File` produces, such as via `Export-Csv`.

Comment: @mklement0 Ok, but I still consider this a bug.